# Convertir un Base64 en XLSX

Tags: angularjs, base64

Tengo un base64 y necesito descargarlo a Excel.
Es algo muy parecido a lo que hace esta pagina, seleccionando DECODE, SAVE AS FILE.
https://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

Este es mi codigo, estoy trabajando en angular.

```
        const pdfUrl = (window.URL || window['webkitURL']).createObjectURL(new Blob([response.Message], {type: 'application/pdf'}));
        const anchor = document.createElement('a');
        anchor.download = `${filename}.pdf`;
        anchor.href = pdfUrl;
        anchor.click();
```

Intente muchas cosas y ninguna funciona, por lo mucho descargo un xlsx dañado.